# How to check an element is invisible via its text

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to be able to wait for an element to be visible where the text = 'Vouchers by post'. However when I try the below, I am recieving a
cannot assign void as an implicit variable and cannot convert from OpenQA.Seleinium.By to OpenQA.Seleinium.ISearchContent.

What do i need to do to fix the below:

```
       public bool CheckBasketHolidayVoucherTextIsNotPresent(string basketLocation)
    {
        var topBasketItems = _driver.FindElements(CommonPageElements.TopBasketItems);
        var bottomBasketItems = _driver.FindElements(CommonPageElements.BottomBasketItems);

        var basketItems = basketLocation.ToLower() == "top" ? topBasketItems : bottomBasketItems;

        By selector = basketLocation.ToLower() == "top" ?
           CommonPageElements.TopBasketItems :
           CommonPageElements.BottomBasketItems;

        var test = _driver.WaitToBeInvisible(selector.FindElements(CommonPageElements.TopBasketItems).Text.Contains("Vouchers by post"), 5);
        return test.All(b => b.Text != "Vouchers by post");
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After knowing the position of your item (By), create a method that will try to wait for your element to appear for 0 seconds (Instant check if there is any element on the page), like so:

```
public bool isElementVisible(By locator)
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(locator));
        try
        {
            new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator));            
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            //Element exists but is not visible, return false or do other stuff
            return false
        }
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        //Element does not exist, return false or do other stuff
        return false;
    }
    //If code reaches this point, element both exists and is visible
    return true;
}
```

You can adjust the TimeSpan seconds or minutes to wait for the element to appear for as long as you like. You can probably make an overload that will take the timeout as a parameter and the "default" function that has no timeout, will call itself with timeout 0.

After all that, you can add some lines of code to the bottom of the function that checks the text of the element and will return if its the one that you want. Returning the appropriate values.